# Sqoop export from HDFS to ORACLE is failing due to special characters in data

Tags: oracle, hadoop, export, hdfs, sqoop

While trying to export data from hdfs to oracle using below command:

> sqoop export --connect  --username  --table
>    --export-dir  --m 4
>   --verbose **--input-fields-terminated-by '|' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-escaped-by '/'** -P -- --schema

Getting can't parse exception for input data as it has website URL's, and _ and date in some of the data fields.

Below is the sample of records in hdfs file that I'm trying to export:

> compID|website|date_fetched

```
sam_140|https://www.sam.com/profile_link_sam|20181212
lok_231|https://www.lok.com|20181212
```

**Parse Exception logs:**

Exception 1:

> Can't parse input data: 'https:/www.sam.comprofile_link_sam' at table
>   name.__loadFromFields(table name.java:1449) at
>   tablename.parse(tablename.java:1272) at

Exception 2:

> org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
>   ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp
>   format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] at
>   java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:204) at

Using sqoop export job, how can we export the above sample data to Oracle?
Please help if i'm missing out any other argument to parse it successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like Oracle (SQL interface) experts a Date whereas you provide YYYYMMDD. So export value to a CHAR column and then convert this CHAR column to a Date column  in ORACLE

Comment: Thanks @Harold. I've added this argument '--map-column-java DATE_FETCHED=java.sql.Date' and exception 2 is fixed. And I'm still getting can't parse input exception: 'sam_140' .

Comment: if I use --input-escaped-by '/' , underscore is causing a problem. Is there a way we can escape multiple characters?